# Start & Stop Javascript function by timer

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, timer

I have the following code on my website....

First, How would I start the animation / function by clicking a link ?

Then, How would I "freeze" the last frame in the animation ? (Possibly by a timer ?)

Thanks.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div id="anim"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#anim {
width: 14px; height: 14px;
background-image: url(http://mail.google.com/mail/im/emotisprites/wink2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var scrollUp = (function () {
  var timerId; // stored timer in case you want to use clearInterval later

  return function (height, times, element) {
    var i = 0; // a simple counter
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
      if (i > times) // if the last frame is reached, set counter to zero
        i = 0;
      element.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -" + i * height + 'px'; //scroll up
      i++;
    }, 100); // every 100 milliseconds
  };
})();

// start animation:
scrollUp(14, 42, document.getElementById('anim'))
```

Here's a Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ctF4t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already prepared for that, read the second line:

```
  var timerId; // stored timer in case you want to use clearInterval later
```

setInterval is used to define a function that is run again and again at
a certain interval.  clearInterval is used to stop this.  At the end of
your animation, instead of resetting the frame counter i to 0 use clearInterval
to stop the animation all together:

```
        if (i > times) { 
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }
```

Here's a fiddle with some extra output for debugging: http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/zcwYT/

Answer (score 0):

Hi could u return js Object handle start and stop .. as `timerId` act as private we can't access from outside function .

```
var scrollUp = (function () {
    var timerId, height, times ,i = 0 , element; 

    return {
        stop : function(){
            clearInterval( timerId );
        },
        init :function( h, t, el ){
            height = h;
            times = t;
            element =el ;
        },
        start : function ( ) {
            timerId = setInterval(function () {
              // if the last frame is reached, set counter to zero
              if (i > times) {
                i = 0;
              }
              //scroll up         
              element.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -" + i * height + 'px'; 
              i++;
            }, 100); // every 100 milliseconds
          }
    };
})();
```

Please see full actions in http://jsfiddle.net/ctF4t/1/ . Hope this will helps you